# Особенность синглтона

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что у меня есть класс GlobalData, где я храню данные:

```
public class GlobalData {
    public static JSONObject contentJSON = new JSONObject();
    public static String textTestResponse;

    public static ArrayList<StatusModel> statusModels = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<StatusModelDetails> statusModelDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Но недавно один знакомый сказал, лучше бы я использовал для этого синглтон. Я прочитал, особенность в том, что у него только один экземпляр. А в моем случае нет ни одного экземляра. Просто вызываю типа `GlobalData.textTestResponse` и все.

Но так как все используют и рекомендуют, хотелось бы узнать в чем он хорош, в чем мой вариант плох?

Comment: Если вы храните объекты в статичных полях, они уничтожаться в конце выполнения всей программы (что на всем протяжении выполнения программы будет забивать оперативную память), если вы будете использовать синглтон, то поля можно сделать не статичными и доступ к ним получать через Instance. Но в любом случае ваш Instance будет занимать ту же память на протяжении всего выполнения программы. Используя сиглтон, вы сможете в любой момент его очистить. Почему бы не сделать поля нестатичными не используя синглтон? Зачем вам хранить данные на всем протяжении выполнения программы?

Comment: Ну, потому что я эти данные использую везде, во всех `Activity` пока не завершится программа

Comment: Почитайте вот тут http://softwaredesignart.net/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/csharp-singleton-vs-static-class/

Comment: в общем, подводя итог основные различия ниже:
 1. Синглтон храниться в куче, статический класс в стеке
 2. Можно склонировать синглтон объект, в отличии от статического класса
3. Сиглтон следует принципам ООП, в отличии от статического класса
4. Мы можем имплементировать интервейсы для синглтона, для статичного класса это делать нельзя

Comment: Так то у меня класс не статичный...

Comment: Вот две статьи, которые объяснят разницу: https://habrahabr.ru/post/103681/ и http://info.javarush.ru/argnist/2013/07/03/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-Java-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-.html

Comment: @TITAN ну тогда ваши статичные поля не будут видны для экземпляра класса и обращаться к ним можно будет напрямую GlobalData.contentJSON . Но они так же будут занимать память в стеке на всем протяжении выполнения программы. И если вы созданите класс синглтон, то эти поля нужно будет сделать не статичными. К ним вы сможете обращаться через Instance. Т.е. вместо 5 статичных полей, вы создаете одно статичное поле, в котором содержится класс с вашими полями

Comment: А изменить значение переменной синглтона в разных страницах получится?

Comment: @user2455111 откуда такая информация -  Синглтон храниться в куче, статический класс в стеке ?

Comment: @Artem Konovalov да, действительно статические классы хранятся в куче

Comment: @user2455111, до этого вы говорили что статические классы хранятся в стеке, определитесь уже.

Comment: Нет, они не хранятся в стеке, они хранятся в куче. Инфа не верная в первый раз была

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не плох. Но есть несколько моментов:

- Вариант со статическими переменными не имеет ленивой инициализации. Т.е. если в программе встретиться название класса, то `jvm` загрузит этот класс и создаст статические поля, даже если вы их не используете. Синглтон, в этом плане, более гибче.
- Синглтон можно передать, как параметр, в функцию. Он может реализовать какой то интерфейс и вообще, подход с объектом больше следует принципам `ООП` нежели статические поля.
- Синглтон можно сериализовать или сделать копию при помощи метода `clone`

Comment: То есть если не считать то, что статичные переменные больше ресурса хавает чем синглтон, волноваться не о чем?

Comment: @TITAN обновил ответ.

Comment: Оказывается, если клонировать сиглтон, то он уже по определению не будет синглтоном

Comment: ну мало ли,  возможна, ситуация, где может  потребоваться снять копию данных и отдать ее куда нибудь.

Comment: А изменить значение переменной синглтона в разных страницах получится?

Comment: Если вы передаете инстанс синглтона то получится, т.к. это просто объект. если клонируете то разумеется нет, в этом случае будет два разных объекта